# DjangoRestFramework - How to get result from different serializers into one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've 4-5 models as follow:-

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    video_link = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(db_index=True,blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @staticmethod
    def get_product_details(product,category=None,image=None,comment=None,rating=None):
        product_detail =  {
                'id' : product.id,
                'title' : product.title,
                'short_description' : product.short_description,
                'video_link' : product.video_link,
                'price' : product.price,
                'user' : product.user.first_name + ' ' + product.user.last_name,
            }

        if category:
            product_detail.update({'categories': ProductCategory.get_product_categories(product)})
        if comment:
            product_detail.update({'comments' : ProductComments.get_product_comments(product)})
        if image:
            product_detail.update({'images': ProductImages.get_product_images(product)})
        if rating:
            product_detail.update({'rating': ProductRating.return_data(product)})

        return product_detail


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_product_categories(product):
        return ProductCategory.objects.filter(product=product).values_list('subcategory',flat=True)
```

Similarly I've multiple models referenced with `Product` as FK, (such as `ProductImages`, `ProductComments` etc) from which I need to fetch the data and then show it collectively under `Product` model using `get_product_details` when fetching the data of a particular product.

So, if I browse to `localhost:8080/product/<product_id>`, it will call the  `get_product_details` which will inturn call the other methods from the models to collect the information reference with the `<product_id>`.

Is it possible to create a serializer in Django-Rest-Framework which will get the data from other serializers referenced to a particular Product obj.??

Following are my serializers.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product


class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategory
```

What I'm expecting is something like this:-

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Product
            include_data_models = (ProductCategory,ProductImages,)
```

My expected output should be of the following format:-

```
[
    {
        "price": 1234,
        "categories": [
            "Tech"
        ],
        "id": 1,
        "title": "1",
        "user": "user full name from User's model",
        "video_link": "",
        "short_description": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on Django REST Framework v3.0+, I would suggest looking at the [Django REST Framework Documentation on Serializer Relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/). In addition, you will want to utilize [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on your `models.ForeignKey` fields.

## Models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    video_link = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(db_index=True,blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User, 
        related_name="products",
    )

    ...


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Product, 
        related_name="categories",
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subcategory  # Tech, Books, etc.
```

## Serializers

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategory


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # The related_name="categories" on the ProductCategory.product
    #    will allow us to retrieve categories, and convert it to
    #    the __unicode__ equivalent.
    # http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield
    categories = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```